# How to set different behavior for same method in Mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have loop:

```
while (set.next()) {
    // something to do...
}
```

`set` object it's mock:

```
final ResultSet set = mock(ResultSet.class);
when(set.next()).thenReturn(true);
```

And I have infinite loop.

How to define `true` from `set.next()` only for first call, and for second call define `false`? Thank You.

Comment: What are your criteria to define the different behavior?

Comment: @Vasyl Lyashkevych first iteration set.next() return true, second iteration set.next() return false.